# How do you check for player death in 1.14.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been googling this for a while to find nothing that works. When someone dies, I want a message like "Lmao you suck"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deathCount` scoreboard criterion.
Create a `deaths` objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

Then put the following in a repeating, unconditional, always active command block. This show all the players who have died the message "Lmao you suck".

```
execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..}] run tellraw @s "Lmao you suck"
```

As `"Lmao you suck"` is a [JSON text component](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text), you can customize the colour and make it bold/italic/underlined/strikethrough/obfuscated (just use a generator [like this one](https://minecraftjson.com)).

Put this in a chain, conditional, always active command block that the previous command block is pointing towards to reset the counter:

```
scoreboard players set @a deaths 0
```